# Concatenating two variables

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two variables

```
var view='Customers',
```

and another global varaible `Window.filters`
the global varaible is an object with Customer as the root,
so when i try to acess it by

```
Window.filters.view
```

it returns undefined because it doesnt transalate view to Customer

when I use

```
Window.filters+"."+view
```

it resolves the part before the concatenation. hence returns an unwanted result. how do I workaround this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bracket notation like this:

```
Window.filters[view]
```

(See also [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors))

Comment: thanks CD it works fine, i cant accept your answer now tho say 9mins